# SIGABRT error in Swift when JSON deserializing

Tags: json, swift, sigabrt

I am attempting to make a Swift application with two main focuses. One is to display all the data from an URL in a ScrollView and the other is a button to get a random name of a game.

The button works and I get a random game but when I try to load the application with the `UIScrollView`, I get a SIGABRT on line 33. 
Any help is appreciated

EDIT: I have since fixed the SIGABRT but I can't seem to display any information into the `UIScrollView`. Anyone see any glaring issues in the code now?

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var infoView: UIView!   
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var labelScroll: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   parseGame()
}

func parseGame() {
    let url: URL = URL(string:     "https://www.giantbomb.com/api/games/?api_key=5094689370c2cf4ae42a2a268af0595badb1fea8&format=json&field_list=name")!
        print(url)
        let responseData: Data? = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
        if let responseData = responseData {
            let json: Any? = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: [])
            print(json ?? "Couldn't get JSON")
            if let json = json {
                let dictionary: [String: Any]? = json as? [String: Any]
                if let dictionary = dictionary {
                    guard let result = dictionary["results"] as? [String:Any]?  else { return }
                    if let result = result {
                        let name = result["name"] as? String?
                        if let name = name {
                            for i in 1...100 {
                                labelScroll.text = "Name: \(name)"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `let result = dictionary["results"] as! [String:String]? //Error line`. Are you sure `result` is a Dictionary where all keys are String, and especially that all values are Strings? Could you give a sample of it?

Comment: Don't use `as!` unless you want crashes.  Instead, test whether the data type allows the conversion you want with `if let`.

Comment: Are you sure it is an issue with your JSON? Go to your connections panel and check that all of your @IBOutlets are connected properly, and not duplicated. The only way I have ever gotten SIGABRTs is through bad outlet connections

Comment: If you paste the JSON data from the url into a JSON viewer, youll see that it is a dictionary and within that dictionary is an array. In each array is the name of the game

Comment: If you have an Array on the Json, so the forcecast will cause a crash, change the error line to: `guard result = dictionary["results"] as? [String:Any] else { return }`

Comment: That fixed the sigabrt. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh no! It's the json parsing pyramid of death!

### A Neat Little Alternative

If you know the structure of the json you will be receiving, you can create some structs to model your data. Also Swift has a cool protocol called "Codable" which does a lot of heavy lifting in parsing json and converting it to an object you create in code.

### Let's Model the Data!

We'll create 2 structs that conform to the Codable Protocol. The first will hold the entire response data

```
struct ApiGameReponse:Codable {
    
    var error:String
    var limit:Int
    var offset:Int
    var pages:Int
    var totalResults:Int
    var status:Int
    var version:String
    var games:[Game]
    
    
    private enum CodingKeys:String, CodingKey {
        //The enum's rawValue needs to match the json's fieldName exactly.
        //That's why some of these have a different string assigned to them.
        case error
        case limit
        case offset
        case pages = "number_of_page_results"
        case totalResults = "number_of_total_results"
        case status = "status_code"
        case version
        case games = "results"
    }
    
}
```

and the second struct to model our game object. (Which is a single string, yes I know very exciting...) Since this particular json data represents a game with only 1 name property we don't really need a whole struct, but if the json was different and say had a "gamePrice" and "genre" properties, a struct would be nicer to look at.

```
struct Game:Codable {
 
    var name:String
    
}
```

### Keepin it pretty

Idk about you, but I don't like to look at ugly code. To keep it clean, we're going to split the function *you* made into two pieces. It's always better to have a bunch of smaller readable/reusable functions that each complete a single task rather than 1 superSizeMe number 3 with a large coke.

### Getting the Data

Piece 1: Get the data from the URL

```
func getJSONData(_ urlString: String) -> Data? {
        guard
        let url:URL = URL(string: urlString),
        let jsonData:Data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
        else { return nil }
        return jsonData
}
```

Piece 2: Decode the data into something we can use

```
func getGameNames() -> [String] {
        let apiEndpoint = "https://www.giantbomb.com/api/games/?api_key=5094689370c2cf4ae42a2a268af0595badb1fea8&format=json&field_list=name"
        guard
        let data = getJSONData(apiEndpoint),
        let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ApiGameReponse.self, from: data)
        else { return [] }
        //Neat little function "map" allows us to create an array names from the array of game objects.
        let nameArray = response.games.map { $0.name }
        return nameArray
    }
```

### Implementation

And finally we can get the names and use them as needed.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        //I recommend putting this somewhere else
        //Perhaps create a method called "setup()" and call it in this class's inializer.
        let names = getGameNames()
        print(names) //Implement the array of names as needed
    }
```